# Why doesn't defining global `void operator new(std::size size)` cause multiple definition link error?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, multiple-definition-error

Why doesn't defining `void* operator new(std::size_t)` at the global scope cause a multiple definition link error?

E.g. the code below compiles and runs, but I imagine that libstdc++ must define a global-scoped function with the same name and signature, no?

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
    std::cout << "Custom new called for size: " << size << " bytes" << std::endl;

    // Call malloc to allocate memory.
    void* ptr = std::malloc(size);

    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    int* p = new int;
    double* q = new double[10];

    delete p;
    delete[] q;

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp && ./a.out
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Custom new called for size: 4 bytes
Custom new called for size: 80 bytes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function overload `void* operator new(std::size_t)` in the global namespace scope has the special property that it is one of the *replaceable global allocation functions*. These and the *replaceable global deallocation functions* follow different rules than any other  function.

They are defined by the C++ implementation, but at the same time a user is allowed to replace them with their own definition anywhere in the program, in which case the default definition provided the C++ implementation is ignored, immediately at program startup. This behavior is impossible for any other function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements